# Question about how SQL and NoSQL manage storage

Tags: sql, nosql, storage, space-efficiency

I'm new to NoSQL. I have this question all the time. As we all know in SQL, data are store in tables where except the first row, are only data. In contrast, NoSQL stores data in Object, which contain at least one pair of key-value.
Does NoSQL repeatly store all keys of every document in storage? If so, can I affirm that SQL is better than NoSQL in terms of storage efficiency?

Here NoSQL, I mean MongoDB. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Space efficiency can mean many different things. What are you trying to do?

Comment: NoSQL isn't a database; it's a general family of databases (graph, key/value, column, document...). There is no one specific way to store data across NoSQL databases. Every database type (and every database *brand*) could have its own way of storing data. There is also no possible way to say whether a nosql database is more or less efficient, storage-wise, than a sql database (again, many brands of sql databases, many ways of implementing storage).

Comment: Responding to the edit: even talking specifically about MongoDB, there's no way to answer this objectively. MongoDB has multiple storage engines, and again, there are many different SQL engine variants, each with their own storage mechanisms.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are mainly asking is if you have for example 1 million documents with 20 keys(fields) each, if MongoDB will save 20 million strings also for your collection plus all the values.

There is a simple way to test it, dont know how realiable but you can make 1 collection with 1 big key, and save 1 million documents for example, and check the size of the collection on
`/var/lib/mongodb`

MongoDB compress the data [Compression in MongoDB collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#compression)

I don't know details of how it works, but i think that compression reduce the disk space of keys. I guess it will similar to a zip file, that when we store 1 word many times, only 1 time is saved, and even a file 20MB becomes few kb.

Its better to wait for better answers or to ask [here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/why-does-a-mongodb-collection-have-more-size-from-postgresql-table-size/107971/16) also, there are people there that know all details of how MongoDB stores data.Ask them about keys storage.

Comment: This is very specific to one brand of database. There's simply no way to answer a generic, broad question about an entire family of database engines. And you can't just tell someone they have "nothing to worry about" regarding storage of things like indexes.

Comment: Thank you. I meant MongoDB here. Sorry for the confusion.